# changing variables inside listview builder

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

i want to change variable values when the widget is loading the data from the web,

just want to do something like this:

```
_playid = _notes[1].id;
title = _notes[1].title;
```

but wherever I put it, i get an error,

I tried to put it in a set state inside listview builder, but no luck since I don't want it with onPress or on tap methods

could someone help, please?

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: when i put it under listview.builder(
it says:
error: Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found. (extra_positional_arguments_could_be_named at [music] lib\pages\playerPage.dart:210)

but it doesn't give any errors if i put it between:
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              title = _notes[1].title; //this is what i want to change
              return GestureDetector(

however it doesn't change the variable value there.

all I'm trying is to set the default value when the json returns data

Answer (score 0):

i just found out, 
simply we have to use setstate in fetch inside initstate

```
  void initState() {
    title = " ";
    fetchNotes().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        _notes.addAll(value);
        _playid = _notes[0].numb;
      });
    });
  }
```